# PHPcrawler - tmp file

Tags: phpcrawl

I downloaded the latest version of `phpcrawler`, and I can access a test website of my own.

I only have an image and some text on this site, I run the crawler and I receive the text minus the image because I did the proper `$crawler->addNonFollowMatch("/.(jpg|gif|png)$/ i");`

I cannot get it to save the *tmp* file It does not save the unique *tmp* file in the folder I run the crawler from, I have tried to save a named file no luck.

I did run into many depreciated errors on different lines in all the php files, for example: `@fopen`, the `@` cause problems in different area's. I use `PHP` and can also do `Regex`.
David.

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question, since I see that `PHPCrawler` questions really do not get answered; I saw a question from last year not answered. I will answer it also, though it might be too late to do any good. This is the answer.

I added in a modified phpcrawler I adjusted for my needs:

```
$fp = fopen('c:/test/poopoo.txt','w');
fwrite($fp,($page_data['source'])); 
fclose($fp);
```

You put it before flushing the file and create your instance of class.

I found out using `PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser` from [this project](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) works well. If you need more control use `RegExp`, but that does have a steep learning curve.

Comment: Congrats on the fix, and thanks for looking out for the PHPCrawler sub-community!  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others may learn from your success.  Cheers~